# Angular and MVC 4.7.2 Bundles not found

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm hosting a WebApi with Angular on local IIS. When I run the app from Visual Studio locally it works fine, but when deploying to my local IIS I get the following error in the web browser console:

[image: 404]

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <base href="/MyAppName/">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Script/Bundles")
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `BundleConfig.cs`

```cs
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Script/Bundles").Include(
        "~/dist/runtime.*",
        "~/dist/polyfills.*",
        "~/dist/main.*"
    ));

    bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/Styles").Include("~/dist/styles.*"));
}
```

And the `Web.Config` is configured as such:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="MyAppName" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm struggling to find out where the issue is. I don't know if I'm missing some IIS configuration, beucase as I said, running from Visual Studio in Release mode it works just fine.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have found the issue, the problem was that I was bundling already minified files and I think .NET was not happy with that.

I fixed that issue by adding:

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

This solved the issue!

Comment: You need more error information to troubleshoot your problem, first you can check the Event viewer, or you can also try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, the problem was that I was bundling already minified files and I think .NET was not happy with that.

I fixed that issue by adding:

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

**This solved this issue, but gave me another one. The page loads for the first time just fine, but after refresh I get 404. Still some router issue, becausing I'm hosting Angular and WebAPI in the same application, but this is another thread.**